# Can I put "the other" instead of "each other" or "either" when there is everything mentioned in one sentence?

Tags: word-choice, legalese

I am stuck in one sentence while proofreading the draft Agreement of the two parties. 
Please help me!

Here is the tricky sentence that has given me headache for the past two days.

*FYI. There are only two Contracting Parties.*

"**The Contracting Parties** shall mutually recognize the identity documents of the crew members issued by the competent authorities of **the other Contracting Party**."

I think that "the other Contracting Party" should be replaced by "either Contracting Party" since all the Contracting Parties are mentioned as the subject in this sentence. And there is nothing left to be called "the other" among the two parties. Is it right?

Any suggestion or advice is welcomed!

Comment: Each Contracting Party agrees to recognize identity documents issued to crew members by the other Contracting Party.

Answer (score 1):

Given that when X is in a relationship with Y, then X shall mutually recognize the identity documents of the crew members issued by the competent authorities of Y:
"The other" means that (A is in a relationship with B) AND (B is in a relationship with A). It has a different meaning from "either," which means that (A is in a relationship with B) OR (B is in a relationship with A).

Thus, "the other" cannot be replaced with "either." However, to clarify the sentence further, one could replace "The Contracting Parties" with "Each of the Contracting Parties."

Comment: "The Contracting Parties" is consistent with "shall mutually recognize".  "Each of the Contracting Parties" is not consistent with "mutually".